# Creating a matrix of histograms from a matrix of numbers

Tags: matlab, histogram, vectorization

I have a matrix with values from 1 to 32, i need to create a matrix of histograms such that (i,j)th histogram will consist of zeros, except it will have 1 on a(i,j). I can do this with loops, but is there a way to vectorize this operation?

Here is the variant with loops:

```
hist = zeros(size(a,1),size(a,2), 32);
for i = 1 : size(a, 1)
    for j = 1 : size(a, 2)
        hist(i,j,a(i,j)) = 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `accumarray`.

```
[y x]=ndgrid(1:size(a,1),1:size(a,2));
hist=accumarray([y(:) x(:) a(:)],1);
```

Comment: thanks. It works, but i don't quite understand how. At least i know what to search in docs!